Windows 10 file properties security tab has no entries
I am on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC x64 (+ all the latest updates, of course). I was working with Photoshop 2024 and when I saved my file it saved it with absolutely no entries whatsoever in file properties security tab, so now I cannot do anything with the file: cannot delete it!
I wanted to add entries there but there is no way how to do it.
QUESTION: how can I delete such file?
BTW: how can this be even done, why in the world Photoshop is doing this from time to time (and only Photoshop is doing it here!)?
UPDATE
And now - all of a sudden - the file is gone just like that by itself! Could it be something with the file manager I am using = Q-Dir?

Files saved in a directory are supposed to have the ACLs the directory is configured with for files - to add the ACLs, you'll need to take ownership of the file, then manually add your user with full control ACLs. When this occurs, what does icacls <file path> return (please add to your question in a code box)?

When a file or folder shows up with no security permissions, this means that you have no permission to view them, but not necessarily means that they aren't there. But in any case, you can always override security permissions by pushing them from a lower directory recursively in that directory (assuming you are owner on a parent folder) if taking ownership isn't working.

Have you checked File Explorer to see what it says, to see if there are any issues with this Q-Dir file manager you're using? Have you looked at the file using Terminal or CMD to see what they say?


Use takeown as administrator to take ownership of the file; being an owner implicitly grants you the access to update the ACL.

Use PowerShell to delete the file as administrator; its internal delete command enables SeRestorePrivilege which allows it to bypass ACLs for the most part.

Use either the "Security>Advanced" tab or icacls /setowner to assign ownership to yourself. Unlike takeown, this also uses SeRestorePrivilege to set an arbitrary security descriptor. Once you become the owner, you should be able to update ACLs in the regular way.

Try rebooting, and/or try using chkdsk.


